# Сравнение двух выборок из одной таблицы

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть таблица `followers`, поля `follower_id` и `following_id` имеют связь с таблицей `users`.

- `follower_id` - кто подписался;
- `following_id` - на кого подписались;

```
id | follower_id | following_id |
---------------------------------
 1 |       1     |      2       |
 2 |       2     |      1       |
 3 |       1     |      3       |
 4 |       3     |      2       |
 5 |       3     |      1       |
 6 |       4     |      1       |
 3 |       5     |      3       |
 4 |       4     |      2       |
 5 |       5     |      1       |
```

Я получаю подписчиков пользователя c идентификатором `1`.

```
SELECT U.USER_ID, U.NAME, F.FOLLOWING_ID, F.FOLLOWER_ID
FROM FOLLOWERS AS F
LEFT JOIN USERS AS U ON (U.USER_ID = F.FOLLOWER_ID)
WHERE F.FOLLOWING_ID = 1
```

Я получаю результат:

```
 follower_id | following_id |    name     |
-------------------------------------------
      2      |       1      | user_name 2 |
      3      |       1      | user_name 3 |
      4      |       1      | user_name 4 |
      5      |       1      | user_name 5 |
```

Дальше я получаю подписчиков пользователя c идентификатором `2`.

```
SELECT U.USER_ID, U.NAME, F.FOLLOWING_ID, F.FOLLOWER_ID
FROM FOLLOWERS AS F
LEFT JOIN USERS AS U ON (U.USER_ID = F.FOLLOWER_ID)
WHERE F.FOLLOWING_ID = 2
```

Я получаю результат:

```
 follower_id | following_id |    name     |
-------------------------------------------
      1      |       2      | user_name 1 |
      3      |       2      | user_name 3 |
      4      |       2      | user_name 4 |
```

Теперь я хочу сравнить первую выборку со второй. И есть есть совпадения установить флаг `t`, если нет `f`.

Как можно сравнить результаты двух этих выборок?

Что мне надо получить:

```
 follower_id | following_id |    name     | is_follower |
---------------------------------------------------------
      2      |       1      | user_name 2 |       f     |
      3      |       1      | user_name 3 |       t     |
      4      |       1      | user_name 4 |       t     |
      5      |       1      | user_name 5 |       f     |
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1f50ff9e0394be9ace6d54e464728b2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT F.FOLLOWER_ID, 
                    F.FOLLOWING_ID, 
                    U.NAME,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN F.FOLLOWING_ID = 2 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY F.FOLLOWER_ID) > 0 is_follower
             FROM FOLLOWERS AS F
             LEFT JOIN USERS AS U ON (U.USER_ID = F.FOLLOWER_ID)
             WHERE F.FOLLOWING_ID IN (1,2))
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE FOLLOWING_ID = 1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5d708884456093b65ad3d0056fa5bab9)

Ну или

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT F.FOLLOWER_ID, 
                    F.FOLLOWING_ID, 
                    U.NAME,
                    MAX((F.FOLLOWING_ID = 2)::INT) OVER (PARTITION BY F.FOLLOWER_ID) > 0 is_follower
             FROM FOLLOWERS AS F
             LEFT JOIN USERS AS U ON (U.USER_ID = F.FOLLOWER_ID)
             WHERE F.FOLLOWING_ID IN (1,2))
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE FOLLOWING_ID = 1
```